# Orchard CMS modules are disabled after remote deployment - How can I fix this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, configuration, web-deployment, orchardcms-1.8

I am new to Orchard CMS and I am trying to get familiar with deploying to a shared hosting service, specifically SmarterASP.net hosting service.  When I asked the SmarterASP tech support why this is happening, they said that they are not experts in Orchard CMS and cannot help me.

I am already looking into other hosting services, but I have a feeling that I am making a beginner mistake.

My problem occurs when I deploy the web app to the remote web site.  In the local app, I changed the theme and enabled a single module,.  After the deployment, upon starting the app, it runs, but the pages appear with the original ThemeMachine theme and previously enabled modules are disabled.

I found a similar posting (on OrchardPros.net) named: "Module not working when published" where sfmskywalker asked if the module (oforms) had been added to the solution project.   I am researching how to add a newly installed module to the solution file.

Below, I have included details about my deployment procedures and the results.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

---

I am working in Windows 7 Ultimate and am using Visual Studio 2013 Community.

I am using Orchard source code version 1.8.1 and a Sql Server Express 2014 database.

The only changes to the original Orchard 1.8.1 app that I am deploying are: 1) I installed and enabled the Theme Editor v1.4.4 module, and 2) I installed the BindTuning Bootstrap theme and set it to the current theme. After these changes, the app runs correctly under Visual Studio.

Using my local IIS server, I created a local web site and deployed the app to that site using Web Deploy. Under IIS 7.5, app works correctly..

Next, I deployed the app to the SmarterASP web site which is configured as an ASP.NET 4.5 Integrated web site.  I ran the remote app and the problems appeared: 1) the page style showed as the original TheThemeMachine theme and 2) the Theme Editor module was disabled.

In the remote app, I changed the current theme back to the Bootstrap theme, and I re-enabled the Theme Editor. The remote app ran correctly at that time.

I then used Web Deploy to deploy the local app, with no additional changes, to the remote server again.   No errors appeared during the deploy operation. However, when I restarted the remote web site, the theme was set back to ThemeMachine and the Theme Editor module was disabled.

I checked the IIS logs from the remote server and they contained no errors.

The SmarterASP hosting service has a 1-click install feature for Orchard v1.8.1.  So, I used that feature to create a new web site.  I ran that app, and added the new theme and module to the remote web site and it worked correctly at that time. However, when I deployed my local app to that site, the problem behavior was the same.

Folder Permissions:
I checked both remote sites and the App_Data, Modules, Themes, and Media folders all have read/write permissions. I also connected to both remote sites using IIS Manager, and confirmed that the trust level was Full (internal).

Comment: I'm looking at a number of hosting providers including ASPHostPortal.  However, because I have a considerable amount of time invested in SmarterASP, I would like to continue to use them if I can solve this problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "...test to re-deploy your Orchard"?

Comment: Thanks for your help Mark.When I make a deployment run, I always document my steps with a text file to (hopefully) prevent duplicating a previous test.  I also try to change only one thing in each run so I can determine if that one change has any effect on my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved

The SmarterASP hosting service is working just fine.

I am new to Orchard and to SmarterASP.net, and I'm making beginner mistakes.

Both Web Deploy (running running from within Visual Studio 2013) and Filezilla (running with stock settings) were both overlaying some files (I don't know which ones).

The key changes that I have made to my deployment procedure are: 
1. Configure Filezilla with two changes:
   - Set the Default Transfer Type to Binary 
   - Set the File exists action to Overwrite file if size differs or source is newer. 
2. When making backups to local Sql Server database, 
   - overwrite backup set (do not append to backup set)

After making these changes, I have been able to successfully deploy v1.8.0, v1.8.1, and v1.9.0 to SmarterASP.net web site with no problems.

This problem has been solved.